# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp, workbench

I'm working with MySQL Workbench and trying to create the tables using SQL requests. I created a model and my tables with what I need and exported SQL code using Forward Engineer, but when I execute the code, this error shows:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT `CodeDep`  FOREIGN KEY (CodeDep)   REFERENCES `test`.`Departement`' at line 7
```

This is my SQL code :

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `test` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`Departement`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Departement` (
  `CodeDep` INT NOT NULL,
  `NomDep` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Nbrens` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodeDep`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`Etudiant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Etudiant` (
  `CodeEt` INT NOT NULL,
  `Noom` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Prenom` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `CodeDep` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodeEt`),
  INDEX `fk_Etudiant_Departement1_idx` (`CodeDep` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `CodeDep`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodeDep`) 
    REFERENCES `test`.`Departement` (`CodeDep`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`Editeur`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Editeur` (
  `CodeEd` INT NOT NULL,
  `NomEd` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Adresse` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodeEd`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`Livre`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Livre` (
  `NumLivre` INT NOT NULL,
  `Titre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Auteur` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dateedition` DATE NULL,
  `nbexempl` INT NULL,
  `CodeEd` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NumLivre`),
  INDEX `fk_Livre_Editeur1_idx` (`CodeEd` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `CodeEd`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodeEd`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`Editeur` (`CodeEd`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test`.`Pret`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Pret` (
  `CodeEt` INT NOT NULL,
  `NumLiv` INT NOT NULL,
  `DatePret` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodeEt`, `NumLiv`),
  INDEX `fk_Etudiant_has_Livre_Livre1_idx` (`NumLiv` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Etudiant_has_Livre_Etudiant_idx` (`CodeEt` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Etudiant_has_Livre_Etudiant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CodeEt`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`Etudiant` (`CodeEt`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Etudiant_has_Livre_Livre1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NumLiv`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`Livre` (`NumLivre`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: I don't think mariadb supports VISIBLE indexes..

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, thanks for your comment, i don't have much experience with sql, can you tell me how can i check the version of mariadb ?

Comment: I changed my comment - I could be wrong in my thinking but try removing the VISIBLE keyword and turn off the option in workbench (see manual)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Why not try taking things out until it works, and then you can report to use what is upsetting the database parser? This can be done very easily on a test database (or a SQL Fiddle).